# dynamically changing an input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this function to change a range input value with javascript

```
changeMenuValue : function(element, newValue){
    document.getElementById(menuElements[element].id).value = newValue;
},
```

the function works for a text input field but will not change the range input
here is an example

```
app.changeMenuValue(rangeElementId, 17);
console.log(rangeElement.value);
```

this code logs the initial value of the element still not the new value (17)

I have also tried the jQuery way

```
$("#rangeElementId").val(somevalue);
$("#rangeElementId").attr('value', '1');
```

Comment: Works for me, http://jsfiddle.net/Ca42a/1/

Comment: Is the element disabled?

Comment: the problem is somewhere else because  $("#rangeElementId").val(somevalue); works fine

Answer (score 0):

the code `app.changeMenuValue(rangeElementId, 17)` passes an id and value to the function but the function `changeMenuValue : function(element, newValue)` expects an element and value.

Comment: Actually, though it calls the parameter 'element', it's used as an index:
menuElements[element]

Comment: yes. i was talking about the signature of the function and the parameter being passed.

Comment: ya sorry thats my object but what it actually ends up being is just the elementId  it ends up being the same thing

Comment: what is the min and max value of the range?

Comment: Whoops. Sorry user3439376, you're right. That's what I get for posting while distracted.

Comment: the min is 0 the max is 100 yet i have no idea why this function is not working